# substring from a string and how much solution

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

Let's say, I have string `programit` and i have bunch of array which is:

```
this.delimiter = ['pro','gram','merit','program','it,'programmer']
```

I need the output become `['pro','gram','it','program','it']`,

#### Attempt

```
this.name = 'programit';
this.newname = [''];
let fakeinput = this.name;
let b=0;
    for(let a=0;a<this.delimiter.length;a++){ 
        if(fakeinput.length==0){
            fakeinput=this.name;
        }
        //console.log(`console ${fakeinput}`);
        if(fakeinput.match(`^${this.delimiter[a]}`)){
            this.newname[b] = this.delimiter[a]
            fakeinput=remove_character(this.delimiter[a],fakeinput);
            b++;
        }
        for(let c=0;c<=a;c++){
            if(this.delimiter[a]!=this.delimiter[c]){
                if(fakeinput.match(`^${this.delimiter[c]}`)){
                    this.newname[b] = this.delimiter[c]
                    fakeinput=remove_character(this.delimiter[c],fakeinput);
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It returns

```
['pro','gram','it','pro','gram','it']
```

I need to make my code not repeat the first delimiter, so it wont repeat `'pro'` value.

Another input and output would be:

#### Input

```
programmerit
```

#### Output

```
['pro','gram','merrit','program','merrit','programmer','it']
```

Comment: `let this.name = 'programit';` is wrong syntax. You can't mix `let` and `this`

Comment: well it's just my fault when posting this. not my actual code

Comment: If you aren't providing an actual code, whatever answer we provide won't work in your actual environment.

Comment: i mean only for `let this.name`

Comment: something can mix up in this platform.

Comment: `this.newname = this.delimiter.filter(sub=>this.name.includes(sub));` DONE

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol no this will not solve this problem, if you notice for `merit` delimiter OP is expecting output to `it`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol your output from string `programit` was `['pro','gram','program','it']`

Comment: @PaulRooney yes, cause you can split the word from `programit` to `pro,gram,it` and `program,it`

Comment: @GigaPudding why your output doesn't include `progr` for the last item in delimiter ?

Comment: @CodeManiac did you mean my result or value in delimiter, if it was my result when `fakeinput` reassign it got overlap in my  second `for` loop. which is array at index 0,1 and got character removed again by same delimiter.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You've stated what you want as your output, but you haven't told us how or why your input is supposed to be transformed, which means it's impossible for us to generalize a solution which would work with your "bunch of array". The only way that would be able to do this is to *guess* at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first approach was matching every character input to my array delimiter, then it remove matched string to delimiter. if my input empty reassign it with input before got `remove_character()` method

thanks to @Nina-Scholz for mentioning search tree, made me do it with different approach, instead of matching every character on my input then do `remove_character()` method on it, why not make a bunch of word using delimiter and do regex match to my input. here's my code if someone in case someone look for it

```
function splitString(array, myInput) {
let temp ='';
let temparr=[];
let fixed=[];
let regextmp;
//let z= 0;
for(let a=0;a<array.length;a++){
    temparr=[];
    temp = '';
    temp = temp+array[a];
    //console.log(temp);
    regextmp = new RegExp("^" + temp);
    let d=0;
    if(myInput.match(regextmp)){
        //console.log(11111);
        temparr[d]=array[a];
        //console.log(temparr);
        for(let b=0;b<array.length;b++){
            if(array[b]!=array[a]){
                regextmp = new RegExp("^" +temp+array[b]);

                if(myInput.match(regextmp)){
                    d++;
                    temparr[d]=array[b];
                    temp = temp+array[b];
                }
            }
        }
        //z++;
        regextmp = new RegExp("^"+temp);
        //console.log(temparr);
        if(myInput.match(regextmp)){
            fixed.push(temparr);
        }
    }
}


console.log(fixed);

}
 const delimiter = ['pro', 'gram', 'merit', 'program', 'it', 'programmer'];
 const input = 'programmerit'; //your input here

splitString(delimiter, input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach and build a kind of search tree through the given array and collect only the parts where the word is found.

```js
function getParts(array, word) {
    function iter([s, ...parts], subset) {
        if (word === subset.join('')) return result.push(subset);
        if (!s) return;
        
        var temp = [...subset, s];
        if (word.startsWith(temp.join(''))) iter(parts, temp);
        iter(parts, subset);
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(array, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getParts(['pro', 'gram', 'merit', 'program', 'it', 'programmer'], 'programit'));
console.log(getParts(['pro', 'gram', 'merit', 'gra', 'mit', 'program', 'it', 'programmer'], 'programit'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can i ask where i can learn those syntax. i'm new to js actually

Comment: i mean this syntax `[s,...parts]` you so awsome

Comment: it is a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with an [Assigning the rest of an array to a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable).

Comment: hey thanks again, but i found in your code, some of my input didnt get me the output i want. when i try to input `'programmerit'`, your output was only `[pro,gram,merit]`. I mean we still can get another output like `[program,merit] [programmer,it]`. I actually found out the solution, thanks to you for mentioning search tree.

Comment: i dont understand what is your input, with what parts and string and what should be the output?